# Confused about the statistical tests to choose or any transformation to apply

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, nonparametric, qq-plot

I am new to the stackexchange, so please forgive me for my editing ignorance. I am confused and stuck about how to proceed further with my data. I have the following data

```
X = [4.04,4.74,4.39,4.40,4.24,4.59,3.95,4.21,4.52,4.40,4.58,3.67,4.64,7.41,4.80,4.62,4.58,5.04,3.44,3.88,4.87,4.98,4.40,4.86,4.70,4.11,4.98,4.12,4.77,4.57,4.94,4.92,
5.35,4.41,4.44,4.76,4.12,4.74,4.63,4.38,4.57,4.69,4.64,4.43]
```

I have prformed some tests (histogram, qqplot, boxplot of samples in **X**  to check if the distribution of my data is normal or not and based on the results (fig.1,fig.2,fig.3) i could conclude that samples have non-normal distribution.

I have 2 possible choices to make to still use 1-way ANOVA and t-test on non-normal distribution.

1) remove the outlier and perform normality test
I observed that there is this one outlier data point in boxplot (fig.3), if i remove it  my sample distributuion becomes normal distribution. However, this will bias my results and analysis, therefore i do not want  to remove it.

2) transform the samples to make data normal-distributed

I performed log transform on the samples,

```
y = log(X)
```

however, they do not become normal-distributed as shown in fig.4

So my questions are as following:

1) is my conclusion of samples are non-normal distributed correct based on fig.1,fig.2,fig.3?

2) what stratagies can i further apply either to transform the data to normal distribution?

3) Would you recommend using non-parametric tests? and how do the results differ from parametric-tests?

[image: histogram of data **X**]
[image: QQ plot of data **X**]
[image: Boxplot of data **X**]
[image: QQ plot after log transformation [log(x)] of **X**]

Comment: The term "parametric" doesn't imply any assumption involving normal distributions; that mistaken premise makes your post confusing. Please avoid using it in that sense. If you mean to refer to some test that assumes normality, simply say that.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b , I have edited my question as you requested. I am interested in using ANOVA and t-test.

Comment: You are correct that the vector `x` in your question does not seem to be normal or lognormal. In addition, the Shapiro-Wilk normality test rejects in both cases. It is not clear how these observations relate to either ANOVA or a t-test. Can you say how the data arose and what your objectives are?